# JavaFX system requirements

Tags: javafx, gluon

I'm trying to find the system requirements for JavaFX?  IE what JavaFX versions are supported with different Java versions.

Using an app running with a Java 11 JDK/JRE I can happily use JavaFX 17 controls but is this officially supported?

There are bug fixes in JavaFX 17 I'd like to benefit from, but I have customers who are still wanting to use Java 11 JRE.

Comment: yes - the min version of java is 11 - see https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ , the getting started section

Comment: Note that the generally-considered most reliable way to distribute a JavaFX application is to bundle it with a compatible JRE (including the JavaFX modules) anyway. Use a tool such as [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like JDK11+ is the requirement. As [the JavaFX 18 release notes state](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/jfx18/doc-files/release-notes-18.md):

> *"As of JDK 11 the JavaFX modules are delivered separately from the JDK. These release notes cover the standalone JavaFX 18 release. **JavaFX 18 requires JDK 11 or later.**"*

This applies to JavaFX 11 through 17 as well.

(JavaFX 11 will work with OpenJDK builds of Java 10 as well, but that is only of historic interest.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).