# JavaFx Subscene in Subscene Text Blurry

Tags: java, javafx

I found that placing a subscene into another subscene would make the text in the sub-subscene so blurry. I had tried to set the cache for the subscene but did not improve it.Below is the minimum demo and the picture to show the  problem.I do not know if it is a jfx bug or incorrect usage.

May I ask how to solve this problem.
I am using jdk version 17 and jfx version 19.

I tried to add sub-subscene root node directly without using Subscene, and the text was no longer blurry.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestSubSceneApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPrefHeight(300);
        hBox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW,null,null)));
        Label label = new Label("123");
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size:30px;");
        Button button = new Button("testButton");
        button.setStyle("-fx-font-size:30px;");
        Text text = new Text("test");
        text.setStyle("-fx-font-size:30px;");
        hBox.setSpacing(50);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(label, button, text);

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 1000, 1000);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        //borderPane.setPrefSize(1600,1600);
        vBox.setCache(false);
        vBox.setSnapToPixel(false);
        vBox.setCacheShape(false);
        vBox.getChildren().add(hBox);
        vBox.setScaleX(0.81231312);
        vBox.setScaleY(0.82341123);

        SubScene subScene = new SubScene(vBox, 1000, 700);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(subScene);

        StackPane content = new StackPane();
        HBox subHBox = new HBox();
        subHBox.setPrefHeight(300);
        SubScene bottomSubScene = new SubScene(content, 1000, 350);
        subHBox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW,null,null)));
        Label subLabel = new Label("123");
        subLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size:30px;");
        Button subButton = new Button("testButton");
        subButton.setStyle("-fx-font-size:30px;");
        Text subText = new Text("test");
        subText.setStyle("-fx-font-size:30px;");
        subHBox.getChildren().addAll(subLabel, subButton, subText);
        subHBox.setSpacing(50);
        subHBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        content.getChildren().add(subHBox);
        content.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREY,null,null)));
        //vBox.setPrefSize(500,600);
        //content.setScaleX(0.81231312);
        //content.setScaleY(0.82341123);
        vBox.getChildren().add(bottomSubScene);

        stage.setTitle("Test Demo");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: “Subscene in Subscne” -> why would you do that?

Comment: Subscene is a standalone component that I encapsulate, and the component can be nested for use.

Comment: The text in the image that you posted doesn't look blurry to me. Also - and I don't know if it affects your problem - I think you should try to match the JavaFX version with the Java version so maybe you should try to use JavaFX 17 (with JDK 17) or alternatively, JDK 19 with JavaFX 19.

Comment: api document "A SubScene is embedded into the main scene or another sub-scene".In Demo that's exactly the way I used it. Scene>Subscene>Subscene

Comment: The same statement is true of and container (for example the `StackPane`s that you use as the content of the `SubScene`). Are you using any of the properties that are specific to the subscene (different depth buffers, cameras, or aliasing)? Otherwise why not just implement this with a regular container (`Region` subclass of some kind)?

Comment: @Abra Zoom in. You’ll find more anti-aliasing on the lower text. Notice the “steps”/chunkiness of curves in the "S”.

Comment: @Abra No, matching versions is unnecessary. JavaFX 20 & 21 requires JDK 17 or later. Prior versions such require JDK 11+. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71957134/642706).

Comment: I was mistaken; the artifact disappears if you set the `vBox` _X_ and _Y_ scales to the same value, which preserves the aspect ratio.

Comment: If you don't snap to pixel or you don't scale in an integer multiple or you scale x and y differently (as pointed out by trashgod), then the system will need to antialias the scene content (graphics and text), and stuff will be blurrier than if snapped to pixel (unrelated to subscenes).  As each line or text won't fall exactly on pixel boundaries the antialiasing will differ slightly from line to line and character to character.  A HiDPI display exhibits fewer artifacts.  Font smoothing can also play a role as pointed out in [Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77253630/1155209).

Answer (score 3):

For the blurry text bug, you can refer to the suggestions from [@crschnick](https://github.com/crschnick). It's related to the text smoothing mode. You might want to check out the fix he submitted.

```
.text {-fx-font-smoothing-type: gray;}
```

For reference, check out this link: https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/jfxcentral2/issues/296.

Comment: I tried set prism.lcdtext true or false,  but the text still looks blurry